# Error to install hyn/multi-tenant on Laravel 8 project

Tags: laravel, composer-php, multi-tenant, laravel-8

I am trying to install the hyn/multi-tenant package in a Laravel 8 project. However when executing the composer require hyn/multi-tenant command, the following error is shown:

```
 Problem 1
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v8.11.2, required as ^8.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.11.2].
- hyn/multi-tenant 5.6.0 requires laravel/framework ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev].
- hyn/multi-tenant 5.6.1 requires laravel/framework ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev].
- hyn/multi-tenant 5.6.2 requires laravel/framework ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev].
- hyn/multi-tenant 5.6.3 requires laravel/framework ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev].
- hyn/multi-tenant 5.6.4 requires laravel/framework ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev].
- hyn/multi-tenant 5.x-dev requires laravel/framework ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev].
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
- Installation request for hyn/multi-tenant ^5.6 -> satisfiable by hyn/multi-tenant[5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.2, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.x-dev].
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve?

Comment: Looks like this package is trying to install an older version of Laravel. `hyn/multi-tenant 5.6.0 requires laravel/framework ^7.0`. So, it isn't going to work.

Comment: hyn/multi-tenant now support laravel 8 https://github.com/tenancy/multi-tenant/releases/tag/5.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the project is not supporting Laravel 8 yet. If you were to look at the source code in GitHub you can also see that the latest commit was months ago. https://github.com/tenancy/multi-tenant

I would suggest using an another package for your tenancy needs, since this one doesn't seem to be maintained well.

Lately I've been doing some testing with https://tenancyforlaravel.com/, it look pretty promising.